# How to map a property for HQL usage only (in Hibernate)?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

i have a table like this one:

```
id | name | score
```

mapped to a POJO via XML with Hibernate. The score column i only need in `oder by` - clauses in HQL. The value for the score column is calculated by an algorithm and updated every 24 hours via SQL batch process (JDBC). So i dont wanna pollute my POJO with properties i dont need at runtime.

For a single column that may be not a problem, but i have several different score columns.
Is there a way to map a property for HQL use only?

For example like this:

```
<property name="score" type="double" ignore="true"/>
```

so that i still can do this:

```
from Pojo p order by p.score
```

but my POJO implementation can look like this:

```
public class Pojo
{
  private long id;

  private String name;

  // ... 
}
```

No Setter for `score` provided or property added to implementation.

using the latest Hibernate version for Java.

**Update:**

In a perfect world it can be done like this (thanks to [Pascal Thivent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70604/pascal-thivent)):

```
<property name="score" access="noop" insert="false" update="false"/>
```

But in our real world there exists [a bug since years](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2925) which nobody seems to care about. So does anyone have a suggestions for a workaround?

Comment: About this noop thing, beware! It will not be part of the mapped Java object, but it will still be present in the HQL memory!

I once wanted to not get a BLOB field as part of the result because they were filling up Java memory but it had to be considered in the query. I thought I was safe but ended up getting OutOfMemory errors because the HQL query was still loading all the BLOBs, even if they were not part of the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `access="noop"` in your mapping to specify query-only properties (that's a secret, non documented feature, see [HHH-552](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-552)):

```
<property name="score" access="noop" insert="false" update="false" ... />
```

---

**Update:** Just to clarify, with the following Entity:

```
public class EntityWithHqlOnlyProperty implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    //...
}
```

And this mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.stackoverflow.q2812672.EntityWithHqlOnlyProperty" table="EntityWithHqlOnlyProperty">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="score" type="double" access="noop" insert="false" update="false"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The following snippet:

```
 Query q = session.createQuery("from EntityWithHqlOnlyProperty e order by e.score");
 List<EntityWithHqlOnlyProperty> resultList = q.list();
 assertNotNull(resultList);
```

generates the following SQL:

```
select 
  entitywith0_.id as id6_, 
  entitywith0_.name as name6_, 
  entitywith0_.score as score6_ 
 from 
  EntityWithHqlOnlyProperty entitywith0_ 
 order by
  entitywith0_.score
```

And **in my real world**, the test just passes. This has been tested with Hibernate Core 3.3.2.GA on Derby and HSQLDB. In other words, it works on my machine (c).

If it doesn't for you - and I don't mean to be rude but - **in a perfect world** you should provide a test case allowing to reproduce [HHH-2925](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2925) as requested for 3+ years. Providing a way to reproduce a problem (I couldn't) highly increases the chances to get it fixed.

Comment: are you sure they didn't abandon this feature? I get a ' org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException'

Comment: @ManBugra 100% sure it's still there (I checked Hibernate 3.2.5.ga, 3.3.2.GA, 3.5.1-Final) and won't be removed.

Comment: with your suggested mapping i get a PropertyNotFoundException. Do i need to configure this accessor somehow? are there any other configurations required?

Comment: seems to be a bug: http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2925

Comment: I deem it didn't work for some people because they didn't specify the type. Hibernate accesses properties in order to get their type while mapping if you don't specify it explicitly.

Comment: Is there any possibilities to configure this property by annotations?

Answer (score -1):

It is giving org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException because you  might have forgot to specify the type attribute of the property in xml mapping.Please give a try.